# setting authorization has disabled hyperlink on Login form

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following settings in my web.config:

```
 <!-- The <authentication> section enables configuration of the security authentication mode used by ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. -->
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="/login.aspx"
           protection="All"
           timeout="30"
           name=".ASPXAUTH"
           path="/"
           requireSSL="false"
           slidingExpiration="true"
           defaultUrl="UserConfigSettings.aspx"
           cookieless="UseCookies"
           enableCrossAppRedirects="false" />
  </authentication>

  <!-- This section denies access to all files in this application except for those that you have not explicitly specified by using another setting. -->
  <authorization>
    <deny users ="?" />
    <allow users = "*" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>

<location path="Images">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="?,*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>

<location path="Styles">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="?,*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

on my login form I have a hyperlink that redirected users to a registration page but since applying the above authorizations settings the link doesn't work, until I log in then I get redirected to the registration page. Can i specifically set this link to redirect users not matter what authorization they have? Here's my form code

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:Panel ID="panelHeaderImage" BorderWidth="1" runat="server" width="660" >
        <table class="Table">
            <tr align="center">
            <td colspan="3"><img src="images/header.jpg" alt="some_text" /><br /><br /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr valign="top">
                <td colspan="3"><asp:Panel ID="panelNavigation" CssClass="Panel" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="650px"></asp:Panel> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr valign="top">
                <td align="right">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblUserName" CssClass="Label_Med_Bold" runat="server" Text="User Name:"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td align="left">
                    <asp:textbox id="txtUserName" runat="server" width="180px"></asp:textbox>
                    <asp:requiredfieldvalidator id="rvUserValidator" runat="server" controltovalidate="txtUserName"  CssClass="Label_Small_Red" errormessage="Please enter a Username" display="Dynamic"></asp:requiredfieldvalidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr valign="top">
                <td align="right">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblPassword" CssClass="Label_Med_Bold" runat="server" Text="Password:"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td align="left">
                    <asp:textbox id="txtPassword" runat="server" width="180px" textmode="Password"></asp:textbox>
                    <asp:requiredfieldvalidator id="rvPasswordValidator" runat="server" controltovalidate="txtPassword" CssClass="Label_Small_Red" errormessage="Please enter a Password" display="Dynamic"></asp:requiredfieldvalidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table width="650" class="Table">
            <tr valign="top">
                <td align="right" class="special_column1">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblSaveResult" runat="server" CssClass="Label_Red_Bold" Text=""></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td align="left">
                    <asp:button id="btnLogin" CssClass="Button_Main" runat="server" text="Login" borderstyle="Solid" onclick="btnLogin_Click"></asp:button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:hyperlink id="hl_Register" CssClass="hyperlink" runat="server" Enabled="true" navigateurl="Administration.aspx">New User?...Register Here</asp:hyperlink>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>                       
    </asp:Panel>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you just need an additional `Location` section in your web.config that allows access to the registration page only:

```
<location path="Administration.aspx"> 
  <system.web> 
    <authorization> 
      <allow users="?,*" /> 
    </authorization> 
  </system.web> 
</location>
```